# JS Counting objects in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, google-apps-script

(newbie question)

I am trying to figure it out why the following code works.

The goal is to create keys from array elements and a .count (number of times the ID appears in the range).

I am approaching it this way.

```js
var darray = [["BM","BM","CC","DD","CC","HH","KK","CC"]];
var obj = {}

for(i=0;i<darray.length;i++){
 
    var codes= darray[i][0]
 
    if(obj[codes]){

       obj[codes].count +=1
    }
    else {
      obj[codes] = {count: 1}

    }
}

console.log(obj)
```

```
result example:
{
BM: {count:2},
CC: {count:3}

}
```

This returns the expected output,but my point is if I miss the else statement, then I get an empty object back and I do not understand why the initialization in the else statement resolves this.
Thanks,

I need to understand the underlying logic of object initialization

Comment: I've changed your code into a runnable snippet so you can see it produces something else then you say.

Comment: How could `if(obj[codes])` ever be true if you remove the only code which assigns a value to `obj[codes]`?

Comment: *"I need to understand the underlying logic of object initialization"*: the principle is clear: if you don't initialise, you don't ... have it initialised. In your case that means the `if` condition will never be true, since that requires the tested value to be ... initialised. What else can we say about this?

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet will only execute the for loop once because it's executing on the outer `darray` array length (i.e., 1). So it only looks at `darray[0][0]`.

You need to use the inner array (i.e., the first element of the `darray`) to loop through the keys.

The second mistake in the code snippet is you need to swap the array query when  getting the `codes`.

If you don't swap the query then you will get an index out of bounds error because it will go

```js
1. darray[0][0]
1. darray[1][0] // out of bounds
```

```js
var darray = [["BM","BM","CC","DD","CC","HH","KK","CC"]];
var obj = {}

for(i=0;i<darray[0].length;i++){
 
    var codes= darray[0][i]
 
    if(obj[codes]){

       obj[codes].count +=1
    }
    else {
      obj[codes] = {count: 1}

    }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Optionally, I'd recommend using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) since objects are meant to be fixed shapes whereas Maps can change shape as you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your code posted here didn't work as expected. I made a few changes to make it work.

```js
var darray = ["BM", "BM", "CC", "DD", "CC", "HH", "KK", "CC"];
var obj = {}

for (i = 0; i < darray.length; i++) {

    var code = darray[i]

    if (obj[code]) {
        obj[code].count += 1
    } else {
        obj[code] = {
            count: 1
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj)
```

I think your question is the following:

*Why doesn't it work without the else?*

Well if we follow the logic, it checks if obj[code] exist, if not he creates this entry into the object. But if you never add this entry to the object, it will never be able to count up any value.

**BUT** it has not much to do with object initialization as this actually happens in the second rule on 'var obj = {}' .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deal with this scenario would be to create a function that takes an array and reduces each item by some value.

Just pass the first item of the array to the function, along with an optional accessor. If none is provided, the value is the item itself.

```js
const computeFrequency = (arr, accessor) =>
  Object.fromEntries([...arr.reduce((map, item) => {
    const value = accessor
      ? typeof accessor === 'function'
        ? accessor(item)
        : accessor[item]
      : item;
    const existing = map.get(value) ?? { count: 0 };
    existing.count++;
    return map.set(value, existing);
  }, new Map).entries()]);

const darray = [["BM", "BM", "CC", "DD", "CC", "HH", "KK", "CC"]];
const frequencies = computeFrequency(darray[0]);

console.log(frequencies)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you attempt to access: `obj[codes].count`. This will not exist on an empty object you've just created, it will only exist if you set the count object which only occurs in your else statement:

obj[codes] = {count: 1} / you tell the object to have the object variable 'count' that uses a number type

so count is an object variable you set manually in your else statement, if you remove it, then `obj[codes].count +=1` will always fail because .count does not exist until you say it does